# We need help with importing & mapping a .csv data extract from a 3rd party system

Tags: import, field-mapping, data

I'm looking for someone who knows CiviCRM's data importing and mapping processes. We have a .csv extract of data requiring some cleansing, importing and mapping. From what we can tell so far the process is multiple steps. We have captured these steps but we wish to determine if it can be developed into a more repeatable process.

We have a test file and schema overview available.

Look forward to hearing from anyone who thinks that can resolve/fix this challenge.

Regards

Warwick

Comment: Happy to give you a walkthrough of importing to see if that is sufficient if this is your first civi import peter.davis@fuzion.co.nz

Comment: Are you wanting information or to recruit a contractor? This site is for the former. You can find a list of partners who can be contracted on the CiviCRM.org website I believe. If you want help figuring out how to do it yourself you've come to the right place.

Comment: You'll find as you go through the process that it is pretty clear. In addition, you can save your mappings with names that make sense to you for future reuse.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I use a text editor with macros to automate the clean up of csvs and then create fields in CiviCRM to receive them. In the CiviCRM import process, simply match the csv fields to the CiviCRM fields.